# Level in binary tree with most nodes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the **minimal** amount of space needed to find out which **level** in binary tree (*random or BST*) has the **most** number of nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to destroy the tree, then you can convert the tree to a linked list while doing a bfs of the tree, essentially simulating a queue with the tree itself!

You can find information about that here: [Convert a binary tree to linked list, breadth first, constant storage/destructive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411793/convert-a-binary-tree-to-linked-list-breadth-first-constant-storage-destructiv)

This requires only `O(1)` space as you have reused the nodes of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

`O(1)`

Traverse the BT (Binary Tree) in Breadth-First-Search approach. Push nodes with mentioning the level of it. You will traverse all nodes in a level and then go to the next level. So just maintain the a maximum variable and keep updating it.

The Queue(for BST) could take space in `O(2^(log(n) -1))`.